# PC without goal / too much general goal. Should I make them on fly?

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques

Do you have any experience with character who's goal is something like "I want to be rich/powerful/free"? I am not sure if I should make goals for their characters during the campaign or just let them roam around the world. Do characters need some kind of motivation to do something? Is it better to do it for some specific goal or better for some general goal that could be anything?
It might be easier to make awesome stories if I know what drives them forward.
Thanks for any response.

Comment: Hey man.  Sorry, we're not a discussion forum, we specialize in answers to specific questions.   You're essentially asking for a wide ranging discussion on GMing and character motivation.

Answer (score 1):

A general goal is still a goal.  Wanting to be rich will affect a lot more decisions than wanting to avenge one particular person.

Just make sure to drop in money related plots.  Quest rewards, thieves stealing their things. The player will be motivated by each thing not just specific quests.

Use this opportunity to explore another PC's backstory, adding a money incentive so that you have 2 PC's interested.

Tldr: a general backstory is okay, you don't need to focus side quests around that character. If they create a generic back story assume they don't want to be the focus.